# Django - How can I stop this repeat query?

Tags: django

So I am trying to retrieve a list of blog entries, which has a foreign key to the author:

In my view:

```
data = {'entries':Entry.objects.all()}
```

Then in my template:

```
<td valign="top">{{ entry.author }}</td>
```

This is hitting the database once per entry to get the authors details. I understand this, but when the author is the same, is there any way to 'cache' the result? For example, if one entry has an author 'relationship' of 1, can I store the results so if any other entries have the same author 'relationship', it doesn't need to hit the database again?

I'm sure this must be possible but I can't find mention of it in the documentation :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. But you can use [`QuerySet.select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.select_related) to pull in the FK information at the same time.

Comment: Sure, but this will do a join for every query. Doesn't really help.

Comment: @Hanpan: `Entries.objects.all().select_related('author')` will do one extra join to pull in the `Author` table, but ensures there won't be any extra queries while you're iterating through the entries in your template.  So, yes, it really will help.

Comment: Strangely, just using select_related did not work, but select_related('author') did. Sorry for my ignorance!